# How can I turn this example into a “2D” slides grid using HTML5?

Tags: html, css-transitions

I am wondering if it is possible to adapt [this HTML5 technology](http://studio.html5rocks.com/#Deck) in 2D, such that e.g. we could use the arrow keys to navigate a 3 by 3 slides grid.

If so, could you indicate a source?

Comment: but there is no 3d in the provided link

Comment: It’s certainly possible — you can move things vertically as well as horizontally.

Comment: @gryzzly — I think he means that the example is one-dimensional, i.e. the slides only move horizontally. Whereas if you have a 3x3 grid, you’d like to be able to move the slides vertically as well.

Comment: @Paul, please see the Edit. Your above comment exactly describes what I am hoping for. Thank you.

Comment: @500: gotcha — no examples spring to mind, I’m afraid. After a brief look at the source, I think that roughly, they’re changing the `left` value of an element when a left or right arrow key is pressed. You’d want to adapt it so that `top` is changed when an up or down arrow key is pressed. Hopefully someone else can provide an example or more detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a plugin written long time ago:
http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html
that allows you to do what you desire with JavaScript:
http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/

This is a brief outline of what you could do with this plugin:

```
(function () {

  // find a current slide by whatever way you want, 
  // i.e. first slide or one that has some class or something...
  var container = $('.container'), 
      currentSlide = container.find('.slide:first');

  $(document).bind('keydown', function(e) {
    var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
    // 37 – left arrow
    // 39 - right arrow
    // 40 - down arrow
    // 38 - up arrow
    if ( code === 37 || code === 39 || code === 38 || code === 40 ) {
      e.preventDefault();

      switch ( code ) {
        case 37 :
          container.scrollTo ( currentSlide.prev(); );
          break;
        case 39 :
          container.scrollTo ( currentSlide.next(); );
          break;
        case 38 :
          container.scrollTo ( // implement finding one that is above );
          break;
        case 40 :
          container.scrollTo ( // implement findign one that is below );
          break;
    }
  });

} ());
```

Note that your container will need to have `overflow:hidden` and dimensions set on it from CSS (or of course you can do that from JS if you want to). You can find all requirements in plugins page.

Answer (score 1):

Google maps has been doing this for a long time.  Google maps are actually huge grids that extend way beyond what your screen could handle.  You get just enough so that you don't bump into the missing ones.  When you're done dragging (rather than clicking right/left/up/down arrows) it retrieves more "tiles/slides/images" via AJAX to fill in the part of the grid that was moved.